# Excel VBA Data Validation to check if data validation in the table has failed

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, data-validation

My below code does two things wrong.

First, it checks for data validation for all the cells in the sheet even if those cells are outside the DataBodyRange of the table and shows MsgBox "Failed".

Second, it shows MsgBox "Failed" even if data validation has not been applied to the cell within the DataBodyRange of the table.

How can I edit this so that it checks only if the Changed\ActiveCell is within the DataBodyRange of the table and shows MsgBox "Failed" only when if data validation has been applied to it otherwise ignoring it?

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Call DataValidation
End Sub

Public Sub DataValidation()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
Set rng = tbl.DataBodyRange

For Each cell In rng
    If Not cell.Validation.Value Then
        MsgBox "Failed"
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

**Edit**

I have tried to modify this code but the Msgbox Failed is not showing when data validation fails

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng As Range
Dim ac As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
Set rng = tbl.DataBodyRange
Set ac = ActiveCell

If Not Intersect(ac, rng) Is Nothing Then
    If Not ac.Validation Is Nothing Then
        If Not ac.Validation.Value Then
            MsgBox "Failed"
        End If
    End If
End If
```